# How can i replace a number within a formula with a value from a specific cell

Tags: google-sheets, formula

maybe it is just easy, but i can not find the answer and tried everything i know, i use a formula to count some values in a row using SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFs($B$5:$B,$H$5:$H,$H5,$A$5:$A,"<=665000000")
```

Problem is, i don´t know how i can use the value i have in A2 to replace the numbers between "<=665000000", maybe someone can explain this for me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want

```
=SUMIFs($B$5:$B,$H$5:$H,$H5,$A$5:$A,"<=" & A2)
```

The & will concatenate the two strings.  You could also do the same with

```
=SUMIFs($B$5:$B,$H$5:$H,$H5,$A$5:$A,CONCAT("<=", A2))
```

And if you need to combine more than one string, use the full worded CONCATENATE() function.  Unecessary here, but to give the idea:

```
=SUMIFs($B$5:$B,$H$5:$H,$H5,$A$5:$A,CONCATENATE ("<", "=", A2))
```

Note that you may have an issue with the first criteria as well `$H$5:$H,$H5`. Make sure it returns what you want.  This is the same as having it be `"=" & $H5`

The best thing to do is to check this with 1 criteria at a time when troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SUMIFs($B$5:$B,$H$5:$H,$H5,$A$5:$A,"<="&A2)
```

The & is a concatenation operator. It concatenates "<=" and the value in A2.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.